# Define a custom rspec matcher that has implementation varying with metadata

Tags: rspec

Using Rspec 3.3 I want to have a matcher which has a different implementation depending on metadata of the example (in fact it's the `:type` of the example as per rspec-rails)

However I can't see a way to either:

- define different custom matchers (with the same name) differently for different metadata (like the way you can with including helper method modules https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-only-some-example-groups )
- access the running example's metadata from the matcher (like the way you can access the running example's methods like http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/custom-matchers/access-running-example)

So for example, I could:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :some_matcher, type: :request do |expected|
  #implementation 1
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :some_matcher, type: :feature  do |expected|
  #implementation 2
end
```

or alternatively

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :some_matcher do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    case metadata[:type]
       when :request
          #etc
    end
  end
end
```

FYI/FWIW, the matcher would be `have_link_to` which expects `expected_href` and then the implementation depends on whether it's a feature/request/controller/mailer -- I have managed to work around this, but would like to see if there's a better way of defining "polymorphic matchers".

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but the (probably hilariously unsupported) way to do this would be

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :some_matcher do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    case method_missing(:class).metadata[:type]
       when :request
          #etc
    end
  end
end
```

This takes advantage of how DSL matchers forward method_missing up to the execution context.

Comment: I confirm this works with rspec 3.7. It would be nice to have an explanation, though.